# How to Add a single user to roles

Tags: asp.net, authorization, auth0

We are using auth0 for storing users with roles details.

We want to update user's role in auth0 programatically though API call. We are following below article,

[User Profile Update](https://fredspharmacy-dev.us.webtask.io/adf6e2f2b84784b57522e3b19dfc9201/configuration/api)

We want to use below URL,

PATCH /api/users/b78a4564-ad7f-4af2-b7b2-79bbe1f703ef/roles

We don't understand which details we need to pass along with this URL.
Do we need to write any rules for this?
If any code snippet is available then it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To update Rules on a user profile, in general means updating their app_metadata - and you use the [update user](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id) APIv2 endpoint for that.

For example, suppose you have the following user profile (omitting some attribute to save space):

```
{
    "email": "bob@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "user_id": "auth0|58585012121212b3ac511f8",
    "app_metadata": {
          "roles": [
              "ROLE_ADMIN",
              "ROLE_USER"
          ]
      },
}
```

And you wish to update the roles information, then you could use the API endpoint for that.

Now, you mention Rules and yes, you could say assign Role information in a Rule which triggers after authentication too. Very simple example of this as follows:

```
function (user, context, callback) {

  user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};
  user.user_metadata = user.user_metadata || {};

  var addRolesToUser = function(user, cb) {
      cb(null, ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER']);
  };

  addRolesToUser(user, function(err, roles) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      user.app_metadata.roles = roles;
      auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata)
        .then(function(){
          callback(null, user, context);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          callback(err);
        });
    }
  });
}
```

In the above, I am just assigning the same Roles to every authenticated user. However, you can do an API lookup / whitelist only certain Clients (using context.clientID) etc - there is a great deal of flexibility.